# Printf fails to print in parent and child after fork

Tags: c, linux, unix, pipe

I'm trying to use `date` and `wc` with pipes on CentOS. I'm not able to `printf` that I'm in `parent` or `child`. Any help is appreciated.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <semaphore.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

/* pipe1.c - send information through pipe.  */

void syserr(char* msg)
{
    printf("%s", msg);
}

void child(int  pfd[]){
    dup2(pfd[1],1);
    execl("/bin/date", "date", 0);
} 

void  main()
{
    int  pfd[2], i, pid;
    char str[] = "Hello World!\n";

    if (pipe(pfd) == -1)
        syserr("pipe");

    printf("pfd[0] = %d, pfd[1] = %d\n", pfd[0], pfd[1]); 
    pid=fork();

    switch(pid)  {
        case -1:
                syserr("fork");
        case 0:
            {
                printf("I'm child'");
                child(pfd);
            }
        default:{   /* parent only */
            if(pid!=0)
            {
                printf("I'm parent'");
                dup2(pfd[0],0); //input
                execl("/bin/wc", "wc", 0);          
            }/*default*/
        } /*switch*/
    }
}
```

Comment: Consider using `popen`. And you don't need to fork a `date`. Read [time(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/time.7.html) and use [time(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/time.2.html), [localtime_r(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/localtime_r.3.html), [strftime(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strftime.3.html) (which BTW `date` is using)

Comment: Replace `syserr` by `perror`

Answer (score 2):

Remember that `<stdio.h>` is buffered, and *stdout* is generally line-buffered, at least when it is a terminal. See [setvbuf(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/setvbuf.3.html)

So you should either end each of your `printf` format control string with a `\n` or call [fflush(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fflush.3.html) at appropriate places. In particular, do a `fflush(NULL);` before your `fork` and your `execl`.

Also use `perror` on failure (i.e. replace every call to `syserr` by `perror`) to understand how system calls are failing. See [perror(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/perror.3.html) & [errno(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/errno.3.html) & [strerror(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strerror.3.html).

BTW, your `main` is incorrectly declared. You should enable all warnings and debug info when compiling (e.g. compile with `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g`). Improve your code to get no more warnings. Then **use the debugger `gdb`** ...

Notice that to avoid [zombie processes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zombie_process), your parent process should use some waiting system call like [waitpid(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/waitpid.2.html) or wait(2) or [wait4(2](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/wait4.2.html))

Comment: Thanks. I've edited the code as you said. Now, It looks like `execl("/bin/wc", "wc", 0);` isn't working. but wc does exist in that path `/bin/wc`.

Comment: Works now. I had to add `close(pfd[0]);` in child, and `close(pfd[1]);` in parent.

Answer (score 1):

**Works now.** I had to add `close(pfd[0]);` in child, and `close(pfd[1]);` in parent.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <semaphore.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

/* pipe1.c - send information through pipe.  */


void child(int  pfd[]){
    printf("I'm in child func\n");
    close(pfd[0]);
    dup2(pfd[1],1);
    execl("/bin/date", "date", 0);
} 

int  main(){
    int  pfd[2], pid;

if (pipe(pfd) == -1)    perror("pipe");
printf("pfd[0] = %d, pfd[1] = %d\n", pfd[0], pfd[1]); 
fflush(NULL);
pid=fork();
    switch(pid)  {
        case -1:
                perror("fork");
        case 0:
            {
                   printf("I'm child\n");
                child(pfd);
            }
        default:{   /* parent only */
            if(pid!=0){
                printf("I'm daddy\n");
                close(pfd[1]);
                dup2(pfd[0],0); //input
                execl("/bin/wc", "wc", 0);          
        }/*default*/
    } /*switch*/
}
return 0;
}
```